# Get javascript to load videos one at a time + autoplay on click

Tags: javascript, osx-mavericks, autoplay

I'm running an experiment where I show videos online and ask participants for a response for each video.

I have 200 videos, however, each of size 1 MB, and javascript seems to insist on loading them all at the same time (which usually crashes my browser).
First, can anyone help me modify the below script to make the videos load only when needed? (say, when the participants click "NEXT CLIP")?

Second, after upgrading to OS Mavericks, the autoplay attribute doesn't work anymore ().. Can anyone get the video to run automatically upon clicking "NEXT CLIP"?

I'm fairly new to javascript -- any feedback is much appreciated.

```
<script>

for (var i=0;i<numberOfVideos;i++) {

var evenI = 2+2*i;   // on even pages, they view the video
var oddI = 3+2*i;    // on odd pages, they input their response

document.write('<div id="page' + evenI + '">');
document.write('<p><video autoplay=true><source src=' + videoList[i] + ' type="video/mp4"/></video></p>');
document.write('<a href="javascript:NextTrial()"> Click here to give your response </a>');

document.write('<div id="page' + oddI + '">');
document.write('<p>How many people were in this video?</p>');
document.write('<p><input name="video' + i + '" type="radio" value="1" /> 1 &nbsp; <input name="video' + i + '" type="radio" value="2" /> 2 </p>');
document.write('<a class="nextLink" href="javascript:NextTrial()">NEXT CLIP</a>');

}

</script>
```

Comment: If you could rewrite the script portion of your question, it would help.  It's not all showing up.  Perhaps try indenting each line of the code with four spaces so SO knows to format for code...

Comment: Thanks for the comment! @Chris actually did that for me :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exact code for this, but you could probably use a handler to wait for the click for the next video to load the next one.

Now, for moving on to the next video, you could make a button, link, or span with an `onclick` attribute to trigger the move to the next function. You could also use above idea about a handler to accomplish the same thing (the first usually would be a lot easier to code and maintain).

Answer (score 0):

**Some logic** *to consider*.

1) We have the number of videos, great - assign that to a variable you can reference

```
var totalvideos = videoList.length;
```

2) Assuming we are starting at video 1, great - assign the current viewed video to a variable

```
var currentvideo = 1;
```

3) We need a html button to progress and skip to the next - great, use it to call a function called ' `playnextvideo()`' that uses the 'currentvideo' variable and the total number of videos.

```
function playnextvideo() {
     var nextvideo = currentvideo+1;
    if(nextvideo<=totalvideos) { playvideo(nextvideo); } 
    else { alert("no more videos"); }

   currentvideo++; /* update the current video variable */

}
```

4) The `playvideo()` function. This could also be called your video renderer, notice we passed the video number to it, In this example, lets say we have an html `div` element with an id of 'videoplayer' above the javascript code.

```
<div id="videoplayer"></div>
```

Back to the javascript and the `playvideo()` function-

```
function playvideo(number) {

var newvideo = "<video autoplay='true'>";
    newvideo+="<source src='" + videoList[number] + "' type='video/mp4'/>";
  newvideo+= "</video>";

/* where we are printing the videos*/
var videoplayerdiv = document.getElementbyId("videoplayer"); 

videoplayerdiv.innerHTML=""; /* remove the old one */

videoplayerdiv.innerHTML=newvideo; /* add the new one */

}
```

5) Start the program by calling `playvideo(0);`

Hopefully not getting caught up in syntax here and I am sure there are mistakes , and improvements - ( not removing the video for one, just hiding it for later recall )

This is how we might approach a job like this. It is good to plot out the components of software first, separating out the  tasks that make up the solution and work on them individually.

- printing of the videos
- navigation of the videos
- attaching the next(click) event to buttons
- handling the end
- handling errors

Hope helps.